# Convert .cpp extensions to .c extension with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c

How do I change my `.cpp` extension to `.c`? Not sure how to do it in Visual Studio. I can have look on the web but not sure if I will have a problem with my project.

Comment: Assuming you mean Visual Studio, you can open the Solution Explorer, then right-click on the filename and select "Rename".  Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project in the explorer and rename it `file.c`

Comment: That doesn't change the VS project.

Answer (score 0):

Open explorer **View > Solution Explorer**, open **Source Files** and rename it `file.c`